# Smart Lock not working, is it due to Outlook?

Tags: root-access, security, outlook, nexus-6, smart-lock

I have a Nexus 6 with Android 5.1, kernel version 3.10.40-geec2459, build number LMY47D.

When I first started using the Nexus 6, Smart Lock worked.
After a while it stopped working.

If I open the *Smart Lock* setting under *Security*, all options (like *Trusted devices* and *Trusted places*) are *Disabled by administrator*

Possible suspects: I use gmail with exchange, I use *Android Device Manager* and I use Outlook for Android.

Is anyone of those apps supposed to stop Smart Lock?

On the [Office Blog](http://blogs.office.com/2015/02/17/pin-lock-updates-outlook-ios-android/) it states

> Further, a device level PIN means we can take advantage of features like native device encryption, TouchID on iOS and Smart Lock on Android

I am not sure of how to interpret this. Does it mean that they "take advantage" of "Smart Lock" by disabling it?

I tested disabing *Android Device Manager* and *Outlook Device Policy* under the *Device administrators* and then rebooted the phone. That did not help.

I would really like to use both Outlook and Smart lock. Is it possible?
Would it help to root the phone?

Comment: It's not the Outlook app, itself, that causes this. But an Exchange server administrator can enforce, either through your Gmail Exchange connection or through the Outlook one, the requirement that you have a PIN. And most of the time when they do this, it blocks Smart Lock. I believe the administrator has power to change that, but few are aware of it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that Outlook Exchange server overrides my smartlock settings on my Android device. I used the default built in Samsung email client to setup my 2 Outlook exchange emails and my smartlock now works as advertised. I would like to find the settings in the Outlook exchange server to defeat this, but so far I can't find it. I am the admin for my own email service from Godaddy and Office 365. So far I can't find anything on a Google search that will direct me to the settings. I still have my Google MSN and ATT emails setup in Outlook and they don't seem to interfere with my Smart lock settings, but now I am split between 2 email clients on my phone.